# How to find the last number of a sequence

Tags: sql, spring-batch, sequences

I am using spring batch in my application. I have an upload process in which the data is loaded in DB from an excel file. The excel has five spreadsheets loaded in five different tables. If the upload is successful then no problem. but when the upload fails, say in the 3rd sheet, I am rolling back the entire upload. This causes the sequence in the first table to skip numbers. How can I solve this issue. My sequence is incremented by 1 and has nocache.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are we talking about Oracle sequences here?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, you most probably have to change your expectations. Sequences usually don't roll back when they were used in a transaction. Example:

1. T1 insert into table A using sequence S to generate PK values
2. T2 insert into table B using sequence S to generate PK values

Now you roll back T1. What should happen to the PKs values in T2? Should they be renumbered? What if someone (like a Java program) already read the PK values?

You can see that even for pretty simple cases, it's impossible to roll back sequences.

Some databases have the concept of `identity` columns where the DB server internally assigns keys but even for those, you will have gaps.

If you really need an uninterrupted flow of PKs, you will have to use your own sequence (or a counter in your Java code) and maintain/reset this one yourself.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I am using separate sequence for each table. In this casefirst T2 is rolled back and then only T1 is rolled back. Btw i have written a java code to reset the sequence once the upload fails.

Comment: The same problem happens when two processes insert data into the same table at once.